# React Native (Expo) Firebase Phone Auth with invisible reCaptcha

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo, recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

Since Expo SDK 37 Firebase Phone Auth is supported, of course reCaptcha is linked to it. Unfortunately Expo only offers the possibility to use a modal to display the reCaptcha as far as I have seen.

Since this modal does not look very nice, is there a way to make the reCaptcha invisible? Or is it possible to display it outside the modal?

Answer (score 1):

To make the reCaptcha invisible, you can pass prop as below:

```
<FirebaseRecaptchaVerifierModal
  ref={/* store ref for later use */}
  firebaseConfig={/* firebase web config */}
  attemptInvisibleVerification={true | false /* experimental - this will make it invisible */}
/>
```

You can learn more about it from https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/firebase-recaptcha/

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own `<Modal>` or display the `<FirebaseRecaptcha>` component inline.

Here what Expo documentation says:

> `<FirebaseRecaptchaVerifierModal>` has limited customisation options.
>   You cannot change its appearance, but you can change the title and the
>   cancel-label.
>
> ```
> <FirebaseRecaptchaVerifierModal
>   ref={...}
>   firebaseConfig={...}
>   title='Prove you are human!'
>   cancelLabel='Close'
> />
> ```
>
> If you want a custom look & feel, then create your own `<Modal>` or
>   display the `<FirebaseRecaptcha>` component inline in your screen. Make
>   sure to reserve enough space for the widget as it can not only display
>   the compact "I'm not a robot" UI but also the full verification UI
>   requiring users to select images.